# How would I go about proving the boundaries and limits of this sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

The sequence in question is defined as $a_{(n+1)} = 6/(7-a_n)$ for all n greater than or equal to 1. also $a_0=2$. I need to prove that $a_n$ is bounded by 2 and 1, that it is monotone decreasing as well as proving its convergence and the limit. I don't know how to do this with $a_n$ itself being depending on $a_{(n+1)}$, plus the only info I was given was that $a_0$ being 2, but if the equation only works for values n=1 and above I don't see how that's useful.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First we prove that $a_n$ is bounded below by 1. We know that $2 = a_0 \geq 1$, and assume $a_k \geq 1$, then $6 \geq 7-a_k$, hence $a_{k+1} = \frac{6}{7-a_{k+1}} \geq 1$. By Mathmetical Induction it's proved.

Next we shall prove that $a_n$ is decreasing. Noted that
$$a_{n+1} \leq a_n \iff \frac{6}{7-a_n} \leq a_n  \iff (a_n-6)(a_n-1) \leq0 \iff 6 \geq a_n \geq 1.$$

$6 > 2 = a_0>1$, hence by the observation above $6 > a_0 \geq a_1.$

Same goes with $a_2$, $a_3$... because $6 > a_0 > a_1 > ...$ and $a_k \geq 1$

We proved that $a_n$ is bounded below and decreasing, by the completeness of the real number set, $a_n$ converges.